# Cumulative sum of 30 rows. SLOW code need improvement

Tags: r

Need help to speed up this code!

Goal is to create a dataframe where the TPS (transaction per second) of the first DF: TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI will be accumulated from record 1 to 30, then reset to 0 and do that again.

This is what it looks like in graph form:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-286za99C5gdHLDErR9B4ZazVrZFFINGaH3xzVMghFk/edit?usp=sharing

My dataset has more than 6millions rows...

I start creating a sequence where I need to reset to 0 my cumulative variable. Then I go through the full dataset and just add on top of the previous value.

I have been running this for a few hours on a quad code x64 8gig machine and still running... so... crazy slow!

Any ideas how to speed this up?  Subsets or some magic with Tables?

Here's the code:

```
# Create a sequence of when to reset the cumulative TPS
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_seq30 <- seq(from = 1,nrow(TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI),by = 30)

# Initialize Dataframe
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30 <- data.frame(matrix(ncol = 3, nrow = nrow(Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI)))
colnames(TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30) <- c("CumulTPS","100%","130%")
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30[2] = 1000*30
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30[3] = (1000*30)*1.3


CumulVal = 0
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30$CumulTPS[1] = TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI$TPS[1]

for(i in 2:nrow(Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI)) {
  CumulVal = CumulVal + TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI$TPS[i-1]
  TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30$CumulTPS[i] = CumulVal
  # print(CumulVal)
  if (i %in% TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_seq30) CumulVal = 0
}
```

The TPS DF is simply a list of TPS on the TPS column and timestamp on first column.

Goal is to recreate what I put in the spreadsheet example, but on millions of rows!

Thanks,

Simon

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use dplyr to group your data into groups of 30 records, then compute the cumulative sum for each value in each group.

Here's some code; note that it needs some refinement to include all values - take a look at the cut documentation for help.:

```
library(dplyr)

# Create a sequence of when to reset the cumulative TPS
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_seq30 <- seq(from = 1,nrow(TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI),by = 30)

#use cut() to add a factor column to the data frame with a different level for each group of 30
TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30$numgroup = cut(as.numeric(row.names(TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30)), TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_seq30)

#aggregate by the new column and get the cumulative sum at each line, within each group
newdf = TPS_Jan7_11h_13h_CheckIMEI_CumulTPS30 %>% group_by(numgroup) %>% mutate(cumulsum = cumsum(TPS))
```

Comment: Thought of that, but I need cumulative sum, row1 = first TPS value, row 2 = first + second... row3 = first+second+third... and so on...  Look at the spreadsheet linked.  blue lines is TPS...green is cumulative.

Comment: You're right - I misread. Sorry. In that case, you'll need to use mutate instead of summarize, and the cumsum function instead of just plain sum. I'll edit my code.

Comment: Can't try it now, but will that simply put the sum "sum(TPS)" group by the 30sec slices.... I really need cumulative.  I was looking in the cumsum function of base R, could I simply use cumsum instead of sum?

Comment: I used cumsum - it should give you the cumulative sum at each line, for each group.

Comment: Please note the edit to my answer from 2 hours ago where I note that you need to play around a little with the parameters of cut in order to cover all values. Cut will set anything that matches the upper and lower bounds to NA. That's where the NAs are coming from, and why cumsum gets NA when it adds them.